# DioErrorType.response: Http status error [415] when Sending FormData via Dio Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, file, post, dio

I am trying to send dio form data with files to an api but this error comes up.

```
Dio dio = Dio(
        BaseOptions(
          baseUrl: baseUrl,
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ${APIVariables.token}',
          },
        ),
      );

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "id": complaint.id,
      "title": complaint.title,
      "description": complaint.description,
      "complainedPosition": complaint.complainedPosition,
      "deptId": complaint.departmentId,
      "typeId": complaint.typeId,
      "priortyId": complaint.priorityId,
      "files": complaint.files
          .map((file) async => await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
              filename: basename(file.path)))
          .toList(),
    });

Response response = await dio.post(
        'Complaint',
        data: formData,
        
      ),
```

**how can I send files with options by correct way and show progress that has uploading percentage, and get response after completion?**

Comment: Status Code 415 indicates that the server side does not accept the file format you've sent, namely "application/json". Can you please check what is the proper format that the server expects?

Comment: this type from api:  
Media type 
application/json
Controls Accept header.

Answer (score 0):

First import http parser:

```
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
```

You need add the content type also for your files like this:

```
  "files": complaint.files
      .map((file) async => await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
          filename: basename(file.path),contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg')))
```

I don't know what is your files type, change `MediaType('image', 'jpeg')` if your files media type is different

Comment: my media type is jpg, jpeg, png and pdf how can I write that?

Comment: you need get file extension from file path. use this: contentType: file.path.split('.').last.toLowerCase()=='pdf'?MediaType('application', 'pdf'):MediaType('image', '*')

Comment: I tried but it's still the same error :(

Comment: Are you sure that your backend server supports all these types? 'application/pdf' 'image/jpg' 'image/jpeg' 'image/png' ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the same as mine. In my case I have to specify the contentType when creating the FormData object. I use the mime package from pub.dev to lookup the media type for me so it won't fail.

```dart
 import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

    FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
          filename: fileName,
          contentType: MediaType.parse("${lookupMimeType(fileName)}")),
    });

    final response = await dio.post(
      "api/uploadFile",
      data: data,
      options: Options(headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}),
    );
```

For further detail, kindly visit my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75464681/flutter-retrofit-upload-multipart-throws-415-unsupported-media-type/75535204#75535204).